# Parse Unicode parameter value in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

My WebAPI Controller is not parsing or decoding Unicode text (Cyrillic, Greek, Chinese...).

For `http://localhost:5001/api/name?search=Србија` search is parsed as ????.

My NameController HttpGet method:

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get([FromQuery] string search? = null)
{ // Here search is ???? }
```

How to help it decode it properly? Or, how to call it properly?

**EDIT**

I should have known better. I knew it should / had to work out of the box, but for some reason it logged "????" to console. Console logging was the problem.

I've added `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` to Program's Main and it "just" works :)

Comment: It should work and it does work on my side without any issues and without any additional settings. I believe .NET has nothing to do with it. Try to check you OS settings

Comment: It was a console logging issue as I wrote in a comment to @Dorin Baba's answer

Comment: It seems that you met the issue about console window can't display messages normally, and, have you succeed with the setting `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` ? Or this is not what you want? Sorry for disturbing you...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to parse the 'search' to [ISO8859-5](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-5) standard? Something like

```
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO8859-5").GetBytes(search);
string searchVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Check if `searchVal` is your desired result. If so, you can try to set the stardard in your web.config file:

```
<system.web> 
    <globalization requestEncoding="ISO8859-5"/> 
</system.web>
```

[Here](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/l-u-cyr/) is an interesting article on this topic

Comment: This is not the answer. As I understand ASP.NET Core does not have Encoding provider for "ISO8859-5". In order to get that provider I would have to reference Windows only dll. Even if I did that it would not solve the problem because text does not have to be Cyrillic. It can be Greek or Chinese.... Maybe my title has mislead you. I will correct it.

Comment: I should have known better.  I somehow knew it had to work out of the box, but somehow it logged "????" to console. Problem is console. I added `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` to Program's Main and it "just" works :)

Comment: @Milan Ok, I think I misunderstood your problem. But still, have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @Felix Appreciate that! <3

Comment: @DorinBaba Yes, as I said it was problem with the display (console) not with API Controller.

Comment: Oh :) Glad to hear that